# Angular2: Http Client and reading from JSON containing a single object

Tags: angular

I am investigating Angular2 Http Client but I can't find out why I cannot do the below.

I read the following JSON file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "surveyType": "Type1"
}
```

into:

```
export class Survey {
    constructor(public id:number, public surveyType:string) {

    }
}
```

using HTTP Client.

In my service I call HTTP GET:

```
getSurvey() {
    return this.http
        .get(this.surveyUrl)
        .map((response:Response) => <Survey>response.json());
}
```

Whereas in my component I have:

```
survey:Survey;

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSurvey();
}


getSurvey() {
    this.surveyService.getSurvey()
        .subscribe(
            (survey:Survey) => {
                this.survey = survey;
                console.log(this.survey);
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        );
}
```

My template contains only:

```
<h1>{{survey.id}}</h1>
```

When executing the code, I always get errors.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined in [{{survey.id}} in SurveyComponent@0:4]
```

The context variable in stack trace reads:

```
context
    SurveyComponent
        survey
            Object id: 1, surveyType: Type1
```

Also in console I see the object:

```
Object {id: 1, surveyType: "Type1"}
```

My concerns:

1. Why the returned object is not of type Survey?
2. Why my survey object cannot be displayed using expression?
3. Finally, how can I get such an example working? The API returns single object, not an array.

I am using Angular2 Beta 11.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [elvis operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#elvis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of survey is loaded asynchronously, its value is undefined at the beginning. You need to check it before trying to display its id property using ngIf:

```
<h1 *ngIf="survey">{{survey.id}}</h1>
```

or using the Elvis operator as suggestives by Eric in comment:

```
<h1>{{survey?.id}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Eric mentioned use elvis operator or provide some dummy default for survey by property init.

```
private survery: Survey = {
    id: null,
    surveyType: ''
}
```